# Why are some Python standard library built-in classes and methods defined, but others have ellipsis stubs?

Tags: python

I was poking around in my PyCharm IDE, and looked at the some of the definitions for error types. I know that these are shadow built-ins, so I did not expect their actual implementation to be found, but what I saw raised more questions:

```py
class SyntaxError(_StandardError):
    msg: str
    lineno: int
    offset: Optional[int]
    text: Optional[str]
    filename: str
class SystemError(_StandardError): ...
class TypeError(_StandardError): ...
class ValueError(_StandardError): ...

class FloatingPointError(ArithmeticError): ...
class OverflowError(ArithmeticError): ...
class ZeroDivisionError(ArithmeticError): ...
```

I know that Python uses CPython-based definitions for many of its lower-level built-in objects, but I'm wondering a few things:

1) Why do some classes, like `FloatingPointError` have only a skeleton `...` but `SyntaxError` has actual data members defined in its Python source?

2) What is the purpose of `...` here? For instance, is this just an artifact of the stub that PyCharm generates for visibility, or is there any reason why the class definitions could not be

```
class FloatingPointError(ArithmeticError):
   pass
class OverflowError(ArithmeticError):
   pass
class ZeroDivisionError(ArithmeticError):
   pass
```

Note, I am sure this is actually `Ellipsis`, and not PyCharm folding code:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure the `...` is actually in the code or just a marker in Pycharm to indicate it is hiding the details? Can you click the `...` or a marker on the left to expand the hidden part?

Comment: @Robert yes I am sure, see my updated screenshot.

Comment: The real Python standard library doesn't have any `class SystemError` definition written in Python syntax at all. Pycharm is synthesizing this code for you as a placeholder for something that is -- as you say -- written in C.

Comment: ...as for why some standard-library exceptions are written in Python and others are written in C, that comes down to matters of implementation necessity. If something is *used by* the C parts that are needed to bootstrap the first Python components, then it necessarily must be written in C itself. Doing that is cumbersome, so one would generally not use it for more of a language than is essential.

Comment: Beyond that, see [What is the rationale for closing "why" questions on a language design?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170394/what-is-the-rationale-for-closing-why-questions-on-a-language-design) -- our scope is limited to *practical* questions, meaning questions whose answers will change how you go about the *practice* of programming, teach you to avoid a specific error, etc.